# How do you find all 'slottable' content?

Tags: javascript, polymer, shadow-dom

In a template (web component), how do you enumerate all the 'slottable' controls?

For example, given I have written a element called 'webtest' and am using it as below. How would I find 'a', 'b', and 'c'?

```
<webtest>
  <div slot="a"><p>...</p></div>
  <div slot="b"><p>...</p></div>
  <div slot="c"><p>...</p></div>
</website>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do this you can use code below to enumerate them:

```
            const toAdd = Polymer.dom(this).children;
            const newItems = [];

            for (let i = 0; i < toAdd.length; i++) {
                newItems.push(toAdd[i].slot);
            }
```